# How to do jscon encode :: pretty print and unescaped slashes at same time in php

Tags: php, json, encode

How can i do the `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` and `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` at same time ?

I tried like

```
$arr = array("success" => 1, "image_url" => $img);
$v = json_encode($arr, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
$v = json_encode($arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo $v;
```

The reason is because i am need to show the response as valid json and slash escaped

```
{
    "success": 1,
    "image_url": "http:\/\/xxbucket.s3.amazonaws.com\/juice\/1457537251ljJmFgyUAY.png"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) takes options as a bit mask. You can use multiple with the | character. So try:

```
$v = json_encode($arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helped me

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$v = json_encode($arr, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```